# How to do user registration in Django REST framework api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have searched the whole web and cant find any satisfying answer
I have changed my user model by adding some custom fields

So now i got 
            'username',
            'password',
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'phonenumber',
            'address'

instead of

'username',
'password',
'email',
'first_name',
'last_name',   --- (these are default)---

This is my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class userinformation(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "User Information"
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)+' - '+self.phonenumber+' - '+self.address
```

Im trying to make a Django REST framework api on which i can post

```
        'username',
        'password',
        'email',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'phonenumber',
        'address'
```

And register user with these details 
what should i add in my veiws.py and serializers.py

Comment: can you provide serializer and view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding these other fields comes from manipulating the serializer.  You could do something like this to expose those fields if you add field `related_name='user_information'` to your model definition:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_information')
```

Then you create a serializer like:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    phonenumber = serializers.CharField(source='user_information.phonenumber')
    address = serializers.CharField(source='user_information.address')

    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name',
            'phonenumber', 'address')
```

and instantiate that serializer in your view:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    [...]
```

Comment: thanks it works good but it stores password in plain text, and i got error "
Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm." is there any way i can store the password which was posted in variable so i can update it by
 u = User.objects.get(username=POST[username])
u.set_password(POST[password])
u.save()

Comment: If it worked, you should upvote it and accept it :-)  As to your other questions since you're trying to set an unsalted and unhashed value to your user model password field you need to hook into [`update()` on the view set](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)